# Linux laptop external monitor

Tags: linux, drivers, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hp-laptop

I have a Laptop HP branded. With i7 6700HQ and gtx 960m. I installed an external monitor. But my laptop didn't detect it. After that I installed Nvidia driver and my monitor was detected and output correctly but my laptop display turns black. I can't figure out what to do. I tired bumblebee Nvidia nouveau and didn't work. It seems like Nvidia GPU can't see laptop monitor. And Intel can't see hdmi.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a correct monitor setup, I suggest you use an Ubuntu-based distribution. All other distributions never seemed to have any good multi-monitor support.

Of course you can install `arandr` or similar programs, but from what I know they won't help you in your problem. And even if they do, it will probably just stay until the next boot.